# Matrix Calculus: Jacobian when two matrices are multiplied

Tags: matrix-calculus, jacobian

Suppose we have a 2x3 matrix **h**, and a 3x4 matrix **W** such that the product of the two matrices is **y**.

**y**=**hW**

How do we get the Jacobian of **y** with respect to **W**?
I can get the Jacobian of the individual elements of **y** i.e. y11, y12 etc with respect to **W** by taking partial derivatives with respect to each element of **W**. But each of them is a 3x4 matrix themselves. So, what is the Jacobian of **y** with respect to **W**? Is there like a way to combine the 8jacobian matrices of the individual elements of **y** with respect to **W**?

Comment: Let $I$ be the 4x4 identity matrix, then [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) of the equation yields a Jacobian which is a matrix
$$
{\rm vec}(y) = \left(I\otimes h\right){\rm vec}(W)
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial{\rm vec}(y)}{\partial{\rm vec}(W)} = \left(I\otimes h\right)
$$

Comment: Recall that $\partial y_{il} /\partial W_{mn}=h_{ik} \:\partial W_{kl}/ \partial{W_{mn}}=h_{ik} \: \delta_{km}\delta_{ln}=h_{im} \: \delta{ln}$.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use indicial notation and calculate. Since you are differentiating a matrix wrt another matrix you will end up with a fourth order tensor. You can then list out the matrices, as you say.